# Volley JSONObjectRequest returns nothing

Tags: android, json, android-studio, android-volley

I want to use Volley to get a JSON response from some website, so I started testing it. Here is my code plain and simple:

```
    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, "http://api.androidhive.info/volley/person_object.json", null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    json = response;
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

    int x = json.length();
```

After the request is made the response is always null. Neither an error is raised neither the request succeeds. Which is really confusing. As you can see I am assigning the value of the response to a variable named `json` which is of the same type. When I debug the application by putting a breakpoint on the `onResponse` method, `onErrorResponse` method and on the last line, the debugger only hits the last line the variables watches indicate that the value of the response is null.

I have tried more than one URL

```
http://simplifiedcoding.16mb.com/UserRegistration/json.php
https://androidtutorialpoint.com/api/volleyString
```

I have added Volley via gradle

```
 compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
```

Comment: Did you add the Internet permission in your manifest?

Comment: Yes, indeed. I have been using the internet permission long before I add the JSON code.

Comment: Volley's `onResponse` is an asynchronous callback, meaning that your `int x = json.length();` is misplaced.

Comment: Yes, you are right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it in a RequestQueue

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
```

Then

```
queue.add(jsObjRequest);
```

Or

```
ApplicationController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the request to the queue for the asynchronous request to work.

RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
requestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);